# In Excel add-in JS Is it possible to read data from other excel files?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins, exceljs

This can be done with a macro VBA, but it seems that the add-in capabilities are limited within the active excel file that it is operating.

But I cannot find a proper place where this is clearly stated.

So the question is, can I read an external (local) excel file from an excel add-in?

Comment: Check out this page, perhaps it gets you somewhere: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-workbooks#create-a-workbook